# Raspberry PI usbmount, dmesg: “READ CAPACITY failed” & “Asking for cache data failed”

Tags: raspbian, usb, mount

I want to mount a USB drive on my Raspberry PI (to use it for my ‘ownCloud’) using a powered USB HUB (running Raspbian). I installed usbmount for this purpose using:

```
    sudo apt-get install usbmount
```

then in: 
        “/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf”

I replaced:

```
    FS_MOUNTOPTIONS=””
```

by:

```
    FS_MOUNTOPTIONS="-fstype=vfat,uid=www-data,gid=www-data,umask=007"
```

Subsequently I attached my USB drive. Unfortunately the drive isn’t mounted, the disk does not even show when I run:

```
    fdisk -l
```

Below is the dmesg output:

```
     [178419.286862] usb 1-1.2.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 10
     [178427.461496] usb 1-1.2.1.4: new high-speed USB device number 11 using dwc_otg
     [178427.563514] usb 1-1.2.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=61b6
     [178427.563543] usb 1-1.2.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
     [178427.563560] usb 1-1.2.1.4: Product: Samsung M3 Portable
     [178427.563575] usb 1-1.2.1.4: Manufacturer: JMicron
     [178427.563591] usb 1-1.2.1.4: SerialNumber: 00000000011E1792
     [178427.581515] scsi3 : usb-storage 1-1.2.1.4:1.0
     [178430.602931] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  M3 Portable      3    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
     [178436.663026] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
     [178447.712119] ................not responding...
     [178583.861417] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] READ CAPACITY failed
     [178583.861455] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda]
     [178583.861469] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
     [178583.861483] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda]
     [178583.861492] Sense Key : 0x2 [current]
     [178583.861510] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda]
     [178583.861519] ASC=0x4 ASCQ=0x1
     [178593.961530] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
     [178604.061573] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
     [178604.061608] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
     [178614.161655] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
     [178635.369367] ..............not responding...
     [178765.561611] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] READ CAPACITY failed
     [178765.561648] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda]
     [178765.561662] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
     [178765.561674] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda]
     [178765.561682] Sense Key : 0x2 [current]
     [178765.561702] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda]
     [178765.561710] ASC=0x4 ASCQ=0x1
     [178775.661602] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
     [178785.761712] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
     [178785.761747] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
     [178785.761770] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

I tried Google and searched the forum, but with no result. Could anyone give me some advice how to solve this problem? I formatted the drive in FAT32 and EXT3 with the same results (the drive does work when connected to my PC).

Thanks in advance,
Bram

Additional info: 
This is the USB HUB I used: http://www.tomtop.com/computers-networking/computer-accessories/usb-hubs/high-speed-7-port-mini-real-usb-2-0-hub-ac-adaptor-c1082.html 
I noticed it does feed back power to my Raspberry PI (model B, 512 MB). However this shouln't be an issue as discussed here: [Powered hubs, backfeeding and safety](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/powered-hubs-backfeeding-and-safety/7308#7308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long shot but you could try using a Y USB cable so that the HDD gets more power. Also look up the USB Hub to see if other people are encountering simular problems.

Could you add the USB HUB model and manufacturer to your post?

Comment: This USB HUB I'm using: http://www.tomtop.com/computers-networking/computer-accessories/usb-hubs/high-speed-7-port-mini-real-usb-2-0-hub-ac-adaptor-c1082.html It works on my PC but after some Googling I found this which looks like mine (though another brand is on it): http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/powered-hubs-backfeeding-and-safety/7308#7308 (through the backfeeding shouldn't be an issue anymore on new models). I'll try another USB device/stick and let you know

Comment: I tried the Y USB cable with the USB HUB but still didn't work (although the dmesg appears to be different). However, it worked when I excluded the USB HUB and plug the three connectors of the Y USB cable in 1) my USB HDD, 2) the PI and 3) a powerpoint (using a USB to plug adapter).

Answer (score 0):

Rob, thanks for your suggestion!
I just tried the USB HUB with a USB stick, which needs less power than my external HDD. And it worked (showed up when using “mount” or “sudo fdisk –l”)! Thus, despite a powered USB HUB was used (which should have enough power for my HDD based on its specs), the HUB probably doesn't give enough power for my 1TB Samsung M3 HDD. This might be caused by back feeding of my USB HUB to the PI, leaving insufficient power for my HDD (since the power is now 'shared' among two devices).
I will try to  take the USB HUB apart and cut a wire to prevent backfeeding (as suggested here: [Powering the raspberry Pi from USB + microUSB, is it safe?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7830/powering-the-raspberry-pi-from-usb-microusb-is-it-safe?lq=1)). Alternatively, if this still doesn't work I will buy a Y USB cable (as suggested above).